# Ionic 3 native-storage error code : 2, no detailed description

Tags: ionic3

I had an error when I used Ionic3's native-storage. It couldn't read the data in native-storage correctly. The error code: 2, but there was no detailed description.

```
  public async getToken(): Promise<AccessToken> {
    let token = null;
    let expires = null;
    try{
      token = await this.storage.getItem(this.ACCESSTOKEN_KEY);
      expires = await this.storage.getItem(this.ACCESSTOKEN_EXPIRES_KEY);
    }catch(e){
      alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
    if (token == null || expires == null || expires < new Date()) {
      token = null;
    }
    return token;
  }
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Error codes contains an integer which specifies the occurred error:

- NATIVE_WRITE_FAILED = 1
- ITEM_NOT_FOUND = 2
- NULL_REFERENCE = 3
- UNDEFINED_TYPE = 4
- JSON_ERROR = 5
- WRONG_PARAMETER = 6

Answer (score 0):

make sure that this.ACCESSTOKEN_KEY and this.ACCESSTOKEN_EXPIRES_KEY are available on the local storage.